# How to change the text color for the percentage shown at the end of the progress bar

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using the Progress bar by `Ant Design` and I want to change the text color for the percentage shown at the end of the progress bar as my background color is black so it's not possible to see the percentage is shown (which is in black color). I have no idea how to change it as there's no API to change the text color.

Here's my line of code:

```
 <Progress strokeColor={{'0%': '#eb5c20','100%': '#c6224e'}} percent={90} status='active' />
```

This progress bar is inside a `div` and even if I change the `CSS color tag` to a lighter color it won't do the job too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the text color using the `color` property on the `ant-progress-text` class. For instance, you could do:

```
.ant-progress-text {
  color: white;
}
```

You might not want to change the color of all progress bars globally, which you can achieve by referring to that specific progress bar using its parent class name (something like `.parent-div-classname .ant-progress-text`).

Alternatively, you can add a `className` property on the `Progress` component to assign a custom class to it, and use that to apply your color css property.

Comment: Tried adding it on my `.less` file but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: Can you share what you added exactly?

Comment: `.antd-progress-text{  
    color: #c4c4c4;
}`

Comment: The class name is `ant-progress-text` and not `antd-progress-text`. You should remove the `d`.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo.. `ant-progress-text` won't work as well..

Comment: Can you try adding `!important` just to see if maybe it's the order of the CSS being imported (from antd and from your less file)? This is not meant to be the solution, but just to debug where the problem comes from.

Comment: Added `!important` and still not working as well.

Comment: Well, there is definitely something wrong. Does your `less` file contain other css properties that are applied properly to other components in your app?

Comment: Alternatively, you can give a `className` to the `Progress` component and use that in your css instead. There is working example [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/18312#issuecomment-521989354). If that doesn't work, then there is an issue with how you are importing your css.

Comment: <Progress type="circle" percent="40" className="red-text" /> and style hte .red-text it in less

Comment: There are few places that override my color:  1. `.ant-progress-text` from `antd.css` file 2. `.ant-progress-text` from `index.less` file 3. `.ant-progress` from `antd.css` file

Comment: Finally works using the `className` !!! Thank you all for the help!! Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```html
<div class = "progressBar">
    <div class = "background">0%</div>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "foreground">0%</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Play</button>
```

CSS

```css
*:not(button) {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.progressBar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.progressBar .background,
.progressBar .foreground {
    width: 150px;
    height: 13px;
    font: normal 10px/13px Sans-Serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.progressBar .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.progressBar .foreground {
    background-color: navy;
    color: yellow;
}
```

JS

```js
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var start = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(start >= 100) clearInterval(interval);
            $(".progressBar").find(".background, .foreground")
                             .text(start + "%")
                             .end()
                             .find(".container")
                             .css("width", start++ + "%");
        }, 10);    
    });
});
```